# Как отобразить один DialogFragment поверх другого?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, dialogfragment, android-dialog

У меня есть диалог сохранения файла, где нужно выбрать имя и путь для сохранения. Он сделан с помощью DialogFragment. Если в выбраной папке уже есть файл с выбранным именем, то отображается другой DialogFragment, который предлагает перезаписать файл. При вызове второго фрагмента закрывается первый. Как сделать так, чтобы первый фрагмент не закрывался, а второй отображался поверх первого?

Comment: можете попробовать Dialog Activity

Comment: сделать то можно, но не нужно. пересмотрите архитектурный подход к решению этой задачи

Comment: Вызывайте во фрагменте диалогалерт